# get element type from element found by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

Im trying to create a function that will get the "value" of any type of any element that has a specific class (textarea, span,... whatever)

To do this I need to test what kind of element Im currently dealing with which I can do easily enough with `alert($('#gdocDump').prop('tagName'));` but for some reason if I grab all elements of the same class with `var varElems=$(".feedback");` and try to loop through them testing each one like `var elementType = elem.prop('tagName');`, I get the error "TypeError: elem.prop is not a function"

1. Why does this happen?
2. Apparently the elements stored in the jQuery object created by
   $(".feedback") are not quite the same as looking at each
   individually?
3. What do I need to change for `var elementType =
   elem.prop('tagName');` to work properly below?

**jsFiddle:**[Testing Ground](http://jsfiddle.net/8WTmT/3/)

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="gdocDump" class="feedback area" rows="1" cols="22" ></textarea><br />
<input id="scaleSlider" class="feedback" type="range"value="1" min="1"  max="9" step="1"/><br />
<span id="command1" class="feedback">This is a span</span><br />
<span id="command2" class="feedback">This is a span</span><br /><br />
<input type="button" id="sendFeedback" value="Feedback"/><br /><br /><br /><br />
<input type="button" id="test" value="Test a specific element"/>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#sendFeedback").click(function() {
        composeAndCallEmail();
});


$("#test").click(function() {
        alert($('#gdocDump').prop('tagName'));
});



function composeAndCallEmail() {
    var varElems=$(".feedback");
    var feedback=[];
    $(varElems).each(function(index, element) {
        feedback.push(getElemContents(element))
    });
}

function getElemContents(elem){
    var elementType = elem.prop('tagName');
    //this is where the problem occurs
    if(elementType=='INPUT')return elem.val();
    //... will add more here later
}
```

Comment: Because `elem` is a DOM node, and you're trying to use a jQuery method. Try using `elem.tagName` instead.

Comment: Based on your comment `This works also` i assume that your question has been answered. Please consider to accept an answer.

Comment: Yes, indeed it has. The site just wouldnt let me accept it at the time since it was answered so quickly. Thanks for reminding me to come back though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `each(index, element)` the arguments are the index and the native DOM element

```
$(varElems).each(function(index, element) { 
    feedback.push(getElemContents(element)) // plain DOM element, not jQuery
});
```

that means you have to wrap it again or use the native `elem.tagName` property

```
function getElemContents(elem){
    var elementType = $(elem).prop('tagName');
    if ( elementType.toLowerCase() === 'input' )
           return $(elem).val();
}
```

Comment: As regards your last point (and not a criticism): don't they? I've, so far, not (knowingly) encountered a browser that didn't. Though I'd be glad to do so, if only to justify my own habitual use of `toLowerCase()` when comparing element tagNames.

Comment: @DavidThomas - I use it as a habit as well, and I deleted the last line right away, as I couldn't think of any browsers that return lowercase either. Still good practice to make sure I guess, as it's not really guaranteed that it will be uppercase.

Comment: @DavidThomas: I'm not sure what exactly you are referring to, but the DOM spec says that HTML tag names are returned uppercase: *"The HTML DOM returns the tagName of an HTML element in the canonical uppercase form, regardless of the case in the source HTML document."* http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-104682815. Unfortunately there can be a difference between what the spec says and what browsers do :-/

Comment: @FelixKling - Then I guess they always are uppercase.

Comment: I wondered myself if the case would be an issue, better safe than sorry I suppose! Thanks!

Comment: @Felix: note that the point to which I referred was edited out by adeneo following the question (but basically summarised as 'not all browsers return element tagnames in uppercase'). Though thank you: I was aware that (in my experience) they all did, I just didn't know *why*. It's nice to have that explained! :)

Answer (score 2):

As commented above, you're calling jQuery method `prop()` on a DOM node; instead use `elem.tagName`.

Similarly in `getElemContents()` you should use `.value` rather than `.val()`. Finally this should give you:

```
function getElemContents(elem){
    var elementType = elem.prop.tagName;
    if(elementType=='INPUT')return elem.value;
    //... will add more here later
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8WTmT/4/).